# Bootstrap 3 datetimepicker unhandled exception

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to use bootstrap 3 datetimepicker in my ASP.net MVC 4 web app for datetime functionality.

I followed the instructions from this post
http://blog.jigsawpieces.me/2014/07/23/lbd-adding-datetimepicker-control-to-mvc-project/
 but when I try running it I get the following errors.

Uncaught TypeError: b.locale is not a function
Uncaught TypeError: k.localeData is not a function

The order of scripts loaded on the page are :

```
"/Scripts/Library/Core/jquery-1.9.1.js"   
"/Scripts/Library/Core/jquery-ui-1.10.3.js"   
"/Scripts/Library/Core/globalize.js"   
"/Scripts/Library/Core/mousetrap.min.js"  
"/Scripts/Library/Core/moment.min.js"  
"/Scripts/Library/Full/jquery.signalR-1.0.0-rc2.js"  
"/Scripts/Library/Core/jquery.pnotify.js"   
"/Scripts/Library/Core/jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1.js"  
"/Scripts/Library/Core/chosen.jquery.min.js"  
"/Scripts/Library/Core/megalist.js"  
"/Scripts/Library/Full/bootstrap.js"  
"/Scripts/Library/Full/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"  
"/Scripts/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"  
"/Scripts/Library/Full/jquery.jqGrid.src.js"
```

Anyone any ideas what is causing the errors?

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old but just incase anyone runs into this problem.

Update your Moment.js library.That is very likely the problem.